# Correctly iterating through array and open pages with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, casperjs

I'm working on a little project with CasperJS. The main idea is to get a links to pictures with title and description from subpages of some website. I already tried many different ways to achieve what I want, but I'm stuck with some piece of code and I don't want to continue with a possibly uncorrect way of coding.

This is current sequence of events in my code:

```
casper.start(url);
casper.thenEvaluate(openPicturesSubpage);
casper.then(getPicturesInfo);
casper.then(getPictureFullRes);
casper.run();
```

First two commands are working as expected, so I will skip to the structure of third function. The code of function (I'm using jQuery, because I need to get some specific stuff in other function) `getPicturesInfo` (variable `pictures` is global):

```
getPicturesInfo = function() {
  pictures = this.evaluate(function() {
    var array = [];
    $('.picture-box a').each(function() {
      arr.push({
        'name': $(this).text(),
        'subpage': $(this).attr('href')
      });
    });
    return array;
  });
}
```

Basically I have everything I need to continue "browsing" for actual full resolution links of pictures. So the next step is to append new data to already created array. This is also the main problem I want to solve. How to correctly iterate through array of previously saved data? So there's the code of the last function `getPictureFullRes`:

```
getPictureFullRes = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
    this.thenOpen(pictures[i]['subpage'], getFullResLink);
  }
}
```

The problem there is that I can't pass counter variable `i` to my function `getFullResLink`. I also tried to add another argument to `thisOpen` method and argument to `getFullResLink` function, but it doesn't work, because method don't have that functionality.

How could I access appropriate index of array inside `getFullResLink`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible ways to solve this.

### Use a closure

Define a `getFullResLinkWrapper` like this:

```
function getFullResLinkWrapper(pictureIndex){
    return function(){
        // contents of getFullResLink that uses `pictureIndex`
    };
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
this.thenOpen(pictures[i]['subpage'], getFullResLinkWrapper(i));
```

This way you can enclose the index variable for each iteration of `getFullResLink`.

### Count inside of the function

It is guaranteed that `then()` steps are not skipped during the execution of CasperJS. So you can easily advance the counter inside of the `getFullResLink` function:

```
function getFullResLink(){
    if (pictureIndex == null) {
        pictureIndex = 0;
    } else {
        pictureIndex++;
    }
    ...
}
```